# org-refile under a given heading

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

From [org-refile to a known fixed location](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/org-refile-to-a-known-fixed-location) I have learned that the argument `RFLOC` looks like this:

`'(heading file regular-expression position-of-target-heading)`

I am trying to programmatically refile a subtree to become the child of a given heading. This is easy, manually, as long as I have `(file :maxlevel . 1)` as part of the `org-refile-targets`.

With point on the heading of the subtree, I call `(org-refile nil nil ("Projects" "/tmp/projects.org" nil nil))`. This does refile to the `/tmp/projects.org` file but the refiled subtree becomes a sibling of `Projects`, not a child.

How can I change my code so that the subtree properly moves under `Projects` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out org-mode provides a function to retrieve existing refile targets, which means if it's OK to set `org-refile-targets`, we can just let org-mode do the hard work of creating the `RFLOC` variable.

This means the code I need is just the following. I go through the generated refile targets and I find the one heading that matches what I am looking for - in this case, a string that ends with `Projects` :

```
(find-if
  (lambda (refloc) (string-match ".*Projects"
                                 (car refloc)))
  (org-refile-get-targets))
```